# Use cases of a copy assignment operator that returns const

Tags: c++, copy-assignment

I have seen code that defines a copy assignment operator to return a `const` reference, e.g.

```
const MyClass & operator= (const MyClass &);
```

I'm confused about the intention, and how such operator can be used.

For example, let's say I use it to do something like `a = b` (`a` and `b` are objects of `MyClass`). Wouldn't that require `a` to have been declared as `const`, and if so, wouldn't that mean that I cannot modify `a`? (i.e. what's the point?)

Comment: *"Wouldn't that require a to have been declared as const"* No, you can make const references to non-const objects.

Comment: It breaks the _"least surprise"_ principle, see the expected function signature(s) here - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment  It will make chain assignments impossible.

Comment: Thanks @RichardCritten which violates the _"least surprise"_ principle? Using `const` or not using it? (I assume the former?)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat but in this case (`a=b`) the compiler would complain unless `a` is `const`, right? and it would also complain even if it was, because we are modifying it, no?

Comment: @RichardCritten *"make chain assignments impossible"* It won't.

Comment: @AmelioVazquez-Reina *"would complain unless a is const"* No, that only happens if you add `const` to the right of parameter list.

Comment: Got it @HolyBlackCat , I assume that's because in the case of `a=b` it would use the default copy assignment operator, and not the one I overloaded?  Or is it for a different reason?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat that's for that.  Had to test it - was a surprise.  It does stop `(a = b) = c;` but not `a = b = c;`

Comment: @RichardCritten Mhm, the next assignment in the chain needs the rhs to be `const T &`, and that's exactly what we return. Remember that chain assignments are evaluated right-to-left.

Comment: @AmelioVazquez-Reina No, overloading a copy assignment removes the implicitly generated assignments. There's simply no reason for it to fail. When you `return *this;` in your implementation, constness is implicitly added, and that's it.

Comment: "The compiler would complain unless `a` is `const`, right?" Why should it? As written, `a = b;` actually requires that `a` _isn't_ `const`, it allows `b` to either be `const` or non-`const`, and it returns a `const` reference. Consider a free function `void print(const std::string& str)`. You wouldn't expect the compiler to complain if you called it on a non-`const` `std::string`, right?